# If/Else in SugarCRM to Set Field Value

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I'm new to SugarCRM and am trying to have a field in the same Accounts Module equal a value when specific criteria is met.

We have four different products that we can sell a customer: ProductA, ProductB, ProductC and ProductD. If anyone of these fields equals **"YES"** I want to set the Customer_Status field to **"Active"**. However if they don't, then they need to be assigned the value **"Inactive"**.

You can achieve this in Excel with the following formula:

```
=if(or(ProductA="YES", ProductB="Yes", ProductC="yes", 
    ProductD="YES"), "Active", "Inactive")
```

However, I'm not sure how to do it in SugarCRM?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Calculated Field using a Formula/Sugar Logic in Studio. Just edit the field "Customer_Status" (I created it as a checkbox for Boolean values instead). Then you can use Formula Builder and enter something like...

**`isInList($product_name,createList("ProductA","ProductB","ProductC","ProductD"))`**

This translates to English as: *"If the Product dropdown equals 'ProductA,' 'ProductB,' 'ProductC' or 'ProductD'*, the value of the calculated field  equals TRUE, otherwise FALSE." Keep in mind the calculated field referred to would be "Customer_Status."